# Can I automatically return Ok(()) or None from a function?

Tags: rust

I have functions that return an `Option` or a `Result`:

```
fn get_my_result() -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    lots_of_things()?;
    Ok(()) // Could this be omitted?
}

fn get_my_option() -> Option<&'static str> {
    if some_condition {
        return Some("x");
    }

    if another_condition {
        return Some("y");
    }

    None // Could this be omitted as well?
}
```

Currently, neither `Ok(())` or `None` are allowed to be omitted, as shown in the examples above. Is there a reason for that? Is it possible for this to be changed in the future?

## Update

We can use [Fehler](https://github.com/withoutboats/fehler) to write code like this:

```
#[throws(Box<Error>)]
fn get_my_result() {
    let value = lots_of_things()?;
    // No need to return Ok(())
}
```

Fehler also allows to throw as Option.

Comment: The first example can be simplified to `return lots_of_things();` (assuming its `Result::Ok` type is the same). But in general, what if the types were `Result<(), ()>` or `Option<()>`? If this was all automatic, how would it decide whether to return `Ok(())` or `Err(())`, or `Some(())` or `None`? I personally think its a good thing that the return values must be explicitly specified and are not automatic. It makes it way easier to understand and read a function.

Comment: Why should it automatically return `None` instead of `Some(())`? Why should it automatically return `Ok(())` instead of some generated error?

Comment: @Cornstalks I would propose a convention. In the `Result` case, if there's no error to return, then I just assume that everything went well, so I would always return `Ok(())` instead of `Err(())`. In the `Option` case, if there's nothing to return, I could just assume that's a `None` instead of `Some(())`. That would be default behaviour, though, the programmer could always explicitly return `Err(())` or `Some(())` if she wants to.

Comment: @Shepmaster Your question maybe is related to my previous comment. It's a matter of convention.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You cannot omit this in Rust. A [proposal](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2120) was made to allow a `()` → `Result<(), _>` coercion rule, but it was massively downvoted and then refused.

[A comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2120#issuecomment-324090179) explains well why it is a bad idea:

> I've gotten very wary of implicit coercion because of JavaScript (yes,
>   I know that's an extreme). I have always loved the explicitness of
>   Rust, and that's why I have favored the other RFC more.
>
> Here is an example of something I'm afraid of
>
> ```
> let x = {
>     // Do some stuff
>     ...
>     if blah {
>         Ok(())
>     } else {
>         Err("oh no");
>    }
> };
>
> if let Ok(_) = x {
>     println!("this always prints");
> }
> ```
>
> Oops... In this case, the type system actually would give false
>   confidence. Scary.
>
> Also, more generally I would like the solution to be specific to
>   exiting a function or block.

---

When I have a lot of `Ok(())` in my code, I create a small helper function to make the code prettier:

```
fn ok<E>() -> Result<(), E> {
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: I took me a while to understand what was going on here, and that's a problem that could happen while I am debugging. I rest my case. Well done!

Comment: I would totally upvote adding that helper as `std::result::ok()`.

Comment: I thought you were Shep.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Nope, there is a Kirbymania in the Rust tag nowadays.